# TypeError: document.getElementById(...) Easy, but please helpppp

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a simple program, actually I'm Network Engineer not Programmer :)
I'm creating this HTML + Javascript for little organization (not for business)
Here's the error Code : TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
And here's my source code, please helpp :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width:1350px;height:600px">
<div id="header" style="background-color:#094AB2;width:1350px;height:50px">
<h1 style="font-family:verdana;color : white;">Preventive Maintenance Analyzer Tools</font></h1></div>

<div id="menu" style="background-color:#DAE0DA;height:560px;width:150px;float:left;">
<img src = "taxi.png" width = "130" height = "130" align = "center"><br><br><br><br><br>
<font size="4"><a href = "http://localhost/home.php">HOME</a><br><br></font>
<font size="4"><a href = "http://localhost/entry.html">CREATE NEW</a><br><br></font>
<font size="4"><a href = "">SETTINGS</a></font><br><br><br><br><br></br>
<img src = "taxi2.png" width = "140" height = "130" align = "center">
</div>

<h2><center>Silahkan Isi Detail Form Dibawah Ini</center></h2>

<div align = "center">
<fieldset>
<legend><b>Detail Onsite</b></legend>
Dari : 
<select name="dari">
<option value="CO">Cyber Office</option>
<option value="LK">Lippo Kuningan</option>
</select><br><br>
Tujuan PM :
<select name="tujuan">
<option value="abb">ABB Sakti Industri</option>
<option value="ace">ACE Life Assurance</option>
<option value="cigna">Asuransi Cigna</option>
<option value="bahana">Bahana Securities</option>
<option value="cimb">Bank CIMB</option>
<option value="dki">Bank DKI</option>
<option value="icbc">Bank ICBC Indonesia</option>
<option value="bni">Bank BNI</option>
<option value="courts">Courts Retail Indonesia</option>
<option value="ffi">Frisian Flag Indonesia</option>
<option value="gel">Great Eastern Life Indonesia</option>
<option value="komatsu">Komatsu Indonesia</option>
<option value="pertamina">Pertamina EP</option>
<option value="rscm">Rumah Sakit Cipto Mangunkusomo (RSCM)</option>
<option value="siloam">Siloam Hospital</option>
<option value="takeda">Takeda Indonesia</option>
<option value="vni">Visionet</option>
</select><br><br>

Cuaca : 
<select name="cuaca">
<option value="normal">Normal / Cerah</option>
<option value="gerimis">Gerimis</option>
<option value="hujan">Hujan</option>
</select><br><br>

Faktor Eksternal (contoh demo, banjir, macet luar biasa dll) : <br>
<select name="fe">
<option value="tidak">Tidak Ada</option>
<option value="ada">Ada</option>
</select><br><br>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="submit">Submit</a>

</form>
</div>


<div id="output" style="display:none">


      <center><h2>Tarif</h2></center>
      <table border="4" ALIGN="center" >
        <td> Tarif </td>
        <td id="output_t4"></td>
        <tr>
        <td> Sub Total </td>
        <td id="output_t2"></td>
        <tr>

        </table>

 </div>

<script>
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(){

  document.getElementById('output').style.display = "block";

  var dari          = document.getElementById('dari').value;
  var tujuan        = document.getElementById('tujuan').value;
  var cuaca         = document.getElementById('cuaca').value;
  var fe            = document.getElementById('fe').value;

  var t1; 
  var t2; 
  var t3;
  var t4;

  switch(tujuan){

    case "abb":
      t1 = 370000;
      break;

    case "ace":
      t1 = 300000;
      break;

    case "cigna":
      t1 = 170000;
      break;

    case "bahana":
      t1 = 375000;
      break;

    case "cimb":
      t1 = 300000;
      break;

    case "dki":
      t1 = 300000;
      break;

    case "icbc":
      t1 = 330000;
      break;

    case "bni":
      t1 = 350000;
      break;  

     case "courts":
      t1 = 350000;
      break;

    case "ffi":
      t1 = 430000;
      break;

    case "gel":
      t1 = 360000;
      break;

     case "komatsu":
      t1 = 580000;
      break;

    case "pertamina":
      t1 = 370000;
      break;

    case "rscm":
      t1 = 370000;
      break;

    case "siloam":
      t1 = 50000;
      break;

    case "takeda":
      t1 = 350000;
      break;

    case "visionet":
      t1 = 20000;
      break;

  } 

  switch(cuaca){

    case "normal":
      t2 = 0;
      break;

    case "gerimis":
      t2 = 20000;
      break;

    case "hujan":
      t3 = 40000;
      break;

    }

    switch(fe){

    case "tidak":
      t3 = 0;
      break;

    case "ada":
      t3 = 30000;
      break;

    }   

  t4 = t1 + t2 + t3;
  console.log(t4);

  document.getElementById('output_t2').innerHTML = t2; 
  document.getElementById('output_t4').innerHTML = t4;
}
</script>

</body>

<div id="footer" style="background-color:#094AB2;clear:both;text-align:center;">
<font color = "white">Copyright : M. Rinaldy Aulia</font></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't see element with id `dari`, I think this'll solve your problem

Comment: Hi @Tushar Thank you for your time.
actually it's not importaint element, I have remove it after your comment.
After remove it, the issue still occurred :(

Comment: Okay, check the same for all the elements, if there exists element with that id

Comment: Hi Tushar,

Yes I have found the issue, it's on the input area..
Which it should be added "ID"..
Thank you so much for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the form elements' values with JavaScript's `document.getElementById();` you'll need to add IDs to each select element.

Currently, you seem to be confusing "name" for ID.

To fix this problem, I'd add and "id" attribute to each select element.

For example,

`<select id="fe" name="fe">...`

You can get value of any element using id in javascript as:

`var fe = document.getElementById('fe').value;`

Comment: Hi Steve,

Thank you so much, fix with your description..